# IBM Cloud Functions: How to target organization and space / namespace

Tags: command-line-interface, ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions, faas

I targeted organization and space using this command `target -o xxxxx@gmail.com -s spaceName`
and it targeted successfully
But when I run `IBMCloud fn list`, it is showing **A target org and name must be specified**

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you targeted the organization and space using `ibmcloud target ...`. See here the [documentation for IBM Cloud Functions on targeting a namespace](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-namespaces#targeting-namespaces). Functions have their own system of namespaces. Initially, they mapped to Cloud Foundry organization and spaces, then moved to IAM-enabled namespaces.

You can list your IAM-enabled namespaces using this command:

```
ibmcloud fn namespace list
```

Thereafter, set the namespace like this:

```
ibmcloud fn namespace target HenriksNamespaceOne
```

Now you can list the objects in that namespace:

```
ibmcloud fn list
```

I strongly recommend to only use IAM-enabled namespaces because they allow better security control. In case of an issue, you could use the following command to see what Functions environment is set:

```
ibmcloud fn property get
```

Thereafter, use `ibmcloud fn property unset --namespace` to unset the namespace property. Then, run `ibmcloud target -o ORG -s SPACE` to target the CF-based namespace. You can also run `ibmcloud target --cf` to interactively target it.

Comment: When I run this command ''''ibmcloud fn namespace target xxxxxx'''' , It is showing is a CF-based namespace and cannot be targeted

Comment: What does `ibmcloud fn namespace list` return? That command only lists the IAM namespaces. Do you have objects in a CF-based namespace? If not, start with IAM and create via `ibmcloud fn namespace create yournamespace`

Comment: idmcloud fn namespace list returns the list of namespaces and I have CF-based namespace. Cannot run fn list commands, even though targeted org and space

Comment: Ok, I added more details on how to unset the current IAM namespace property and set a CF namespace. Let me know if that works